# CLion MakeFile Build Failure

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, clion

When I Try to build CPP Project with MakeFile I have the next error:
CreateProcess error=2
Cannot run program "make" (in directory [Path])
[image]

Comment: Have you installed a `make` program?  Is it on your `PATH`?  If you run `make` from a shell prompt does it work?

Comment: It was installed but not in PATH. Thank you very much!